# jquery form validation with regex

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
             <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                 var usernameReg=/^[a-zA-Z ]$/;
                 var mobnumReg=/^[0-9]$/;
                 var emailReg=/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

                 var errors=false;
                if($('#username').val()==''){
                    $('#username').after('<span class="errors">missing name</span>');   
                    errors=true;
                }
                if($('#mobnum').val()==''){
                    $('#mobnum').after('<span class="errors">missing number</span>');
                    errors=true;
                }
                if($('#mail').val()==''){
                    $('#mail').after('<span class="errors">missing mail</span>');   
                    errors=true;
                }
                if($('#pwd').val()==''){
                    $('#pwd').after('<span class="errors">missing password</span>');
                    errors=true;    
                }
                if($('#addr1').val()==''){
                    $('#addr1').after('<span class="errors">missing address</span>');   
                    errors=true;
                }
                if($('#addr2').val()==''){
                    $('#addr2').after('<span class="errors">missing address</span>');
                    errors=true;    
                }
                if(errors==true){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }); });

        </script>    
        </head>
        <body>

         <form method="post" id="user_form">

                NAME <br>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="req" ><br>
                MOBILE NUMBER <br>
                <input type="text" name="mobnum" id="mobnum" class="req" maxlength="10"><br>
                E-MAIL <br>
                <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" class="req" ><br>    
                PASSWORD <br>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="req" ><br>    
                ADDRESS 1<br>
                <input type="text" name="addr1" id="addr1" class="req" ><br>
                ADDRESS 2<br>
                <input type="text" name="addr2" id="addr2" class="req" ><br>
                <button type="submit"  id="submit">Submit</button>

         </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

hi.. i have written code for jquery form validation with regex... here error message displayed only for incorrect email..if i type incorrect user name and mobile number it should show error message .... how to add pattern for that ?

Comment: The way you are using for validation is not so good, I will recommend you to use Jquery validation plugin.

Comment: i am trying without using plugin

Comment: ok. but, how many times you can write if...else block and take manual efforts, if the plug-in is available.

Comment: ok @NitinDhomse

Comment: You just have written some patterns and initialized them into `usernameReg`, `mobnumReg` and `emailReg` variables .. you need to apply them on the way of inputs.

Comment: yes completed..thanks @Shafizadeh

Comment: our email regex matches `---@-----` that is not a valid mail but it doesn't match `me@localhost` or `abcdef@abcdef.museum` that are valid emails.

Comment: @Toto `---@-----` is valid as a dead man's email `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned in the comments, you should apply your patterns on the way of inputs. Try this:

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                 var usernameReg=/^[a-zA-Z ]$/;
                 var mobnumReg=/^[0-9]$/;
                 var emailReg=/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                 var username = $('#username').val(),
                     mobnum = $('#mobnum').val(),
                     mail = $('#mail').val();

                 var errors=false;
                if(username == '' ||  !usernameReg.test(username)){
                    $('#username').after('<span class="errors">missing name</span>');   
                    errors=true;
                }
                if(mobnum == '' || !mobnumReg.test(mobnum)){
                    $('#mobnum').after('<span class="errors">missing number</span>');
                    errors=true;
                }
                if(mail == '' || !emailReg.test(mail)){
                    $('#mail').after('<span class="errors">missing mail</span>');   
                    errors=true;
                }
                if($('#pwd').val()==''){
                    $('#pwd').after('<span class="errors">missing password</span>');
                    errors=true;    
                }
                if($('#addr1').val()==''){
                    $('#addr1').after('<span class="errors">missing address</span>');   
                    errors=true;
                }
                if($('#addr2').val()==''){
                    $('#addr2').after('<span class="errors">missing address</span>');
                    errors=true;    
                }
                if(errors==true){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
         <form method="post" id="user_form">

                NAME <br>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="req" ><br>
                MOBILE NUMBER <br>
                <input type="text" name="mobnum" id="mobnum" class="req" maxlength="10"><br>
                E-MAIL <br>
                <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" class="req" ><br>    
                PASSWORD <br>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="req" ><br>    
                ADDRESS 1<br>
                <input type="text" name="addr1" id="addr1" class="req" ><br>
                ADDRESS 2<br>
                <input type="text" name="addr2" id="addr2" class="req" ><br>
                <button type="submit"  id="submit">Submit</button>

         </form>
```

Noted that you may want to improve your error messages. `missing name` isn't enough anymore. You should say: `either missing name or wrong pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

@Shafizadeh fixed your code just fine. Just a remark: You can do that validation also in HTML alone. Required fields:

```
<input name="username" required>
```

Fields matching a pattern:

```
<input name="mobnum" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]+">
```

Basically all modern browsers do support these features nowadays. If you need some level of interoperability , though, I've written a library, [Hyperform](https://hyperform.js.org), that makes sure these properties work as far back as IE 10.

Comment: Good point ..! [`pattern`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) is a great attribute in HTML5 ..! I like it `;-)`